# How to get the top-right (x,y) co-ordinates of a table row

Tags: jquery

Table row example:

```
<tr class="row"><td>Blah</td><td>Blah 2</td></tr>
```

how to go from here:

```
$('row').click(function(){

});
```

So when a td cell of the row is clicked on, if gives me the (x,y) co-ordinates of the top right corner of the row?

Comment: Use jQuerys `.offset()`.

Comment: Are you asking for the offset of the td in relation to it's parent tr? Or are you asking for the offset of the tr in relation to a different parent container or body of the document?

Comment: The second one Tim. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) or [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/), depending on what the distance should be relative of:

```
$('row').click(function(){
    $(this).offset(); //returns an object with top and left values relative to the document
    //or
    $(this).position(); //returns an object with top and left values relative to the parent
});
```

normally used like so (same for both methods) :

```
 $('row').click(function(){
     var left = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width(),
          top = $(this).offset().top;
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give the top left corner not the top right corner though?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to add the width of the row.